# Casting a nullable in where clause in LinQ-to-entity without null-check

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-entities

I know I can't cast a nullable int with the value of 'null' into a non-nullable.

```
int? v = null;
int w = (int)v;
```

So I started by making my where clause with a null check. But now I see it seems to still works even without it, how is that possible?

I know I have many `LogEmneId`that is null in the database.

```
foreach (var logMaaler in ctx.LogMaalers.Where(lm =>
              // (lm.LogEmneId != null && logEmner.Contains((short)lm.LogEmneId))
                                          logEmner.Contains((short)lm.LogEmneId)
                                                ))
{
}
```

Does the LinQ-to-entity statement get rewritten as a sql query that handles the null check for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the LinQ-to-entity statement get rewritten as a sql query that handles the null check for me?

Kind of. `Contains` is transformed into `IN` clause within SQL query, which works just fine with `NULL` values. Consider following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

It will work just fine when you have a row with `NULL` in `Id` column. And that's exactly what's happening here.

Comment: Thanks, then I will skip my own check that it is redundant.